# How to open the Watch Window in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I search on Google about "Visual Studio 2019 Watch Window". It tells me that open the Watch Window by the menu sequence **Debug > Windows > Watch**. However there is no an **Watch** item in the Windows menu. Can anybody tell me how to open the **Watch** window?

[image]

Comment: Run it. Then `CTRL+ALT+W + 1,2,3,4`. Or open the Menu. Or pin it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

button becomes visible when in debug mode, debug> window> watch

Answer (score 2):

Add a breakpoint in your code, and then click "start debugging(F5)". Then Select DEBUG -> Windows -> Watch

Have you already started debugging? The watch window option is only visible under DEBUG -> Windows during debugging (debugger must be running or in break mode).